# File.length() returns 0

Tags: java, file, content-length

I'm trying to get the length (in bytes) of some files. The problem is that I get a zero for their length while they are not of length zero (I checked!)

Moreover, every other file's method I'm using on these files works just fine. so it's just the issue with the length.

why this happening?

thank you.

```
    //add all files names in the directory into array
    String[] files = new File(sourcedir).list();
    filesNamesList.addAll(Arrays.asList(files));
    filesNamesList.removeIf(name -> ((new File(sourcedir + PATH_BACK_SLASH + name))
            .isDirectory()));

    for (String f:files){
        File e =  new File(f);
        System.out.println((e).length());

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with your problem but when removing the directories from your list, try using the constructor `File(sourcedir, name)`

Comment: the output was:
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
(each 0 in a different line, for 12 different file objects)

Comment: Have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149785/get-size-of-folder-or-file

Comment: Looks like duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962575/java-io-file-length-returns-0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get size of folder or file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149785/get-size-of-folder-or-file)

Answer (score 1):

It is worth checking the Absolute path of a file using **File.getAbsolutePath()** to make sure whether the function is given with the right path to the file or not.

Answer (score 1):

The `list()` method that you're using lists the file *names*, not their *absolute paths*.

So your code lists all file names in `sourcedir` (not their full paths), then looks for those same file names in the *current directory you're running your program from.* That's why `length()` returns 0 for all those files ([as per the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length()), it'll return 0 if the file doesn't exist.)

If you instead want a list of all the *absolute paths*, then you can do that concisely using streams like so:

```
List<String> files = Arrays.stream(new File("C:\\users\\michael\\desktop").listFiles())
        .map(f -> f.getAbsolutePath())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, if all these files are only ever going to be from the same directory, then use `new File(sourcedir, name)` in your for loop (this is a better alternative than the `new File(sourcedir + PATH_BACK_SLASH + name)` you use elsewhere.)

Answer (score 0):

**Your file paths are possibly incorrect.**

Java's [File.length() Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length()) states that `length()` may return 0L if the file is not found.

> The length, in bytes, of the file denoted by this abstract pathname, or 0L if the file does not exist. Some operating systems may return 0L for pathnames denoting system-dependent entities such as devices or pipes."

Therefore, if you're certain your files have content in them, then you are likely not finding them correctly. Double check your file paths and try again.

Also, the javadoc recommends using [Files.readAttributes()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAttributes(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) if you need more detailed error information; I echo their sentiment here.

Comment: thanks! I should have used the absolute path of the files and not just their names. thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer worked for you, please consider upvoting. And definitely click the check mark to accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that those files does not contain any contents in them. So you are getting 0 as the output

Comment: but all of them do contain contents in them.

Comment: and I see in their properties in the directory they are at that they are not of length zero: 35.8 KB,13.8 KB, etc.